# Creating a compressing function in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So i've been asked for creating a function that compress a string. 
I tried to create a javascript function to do that. But it seems, it is not doing anything for the moment. I don't understand why, regardless of the input, my function is not doing anything.

```js
function compression(input) {
  var charsToEscape = "#/%&+,!()*':;<=>?";
  var escaped = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var testChar = input.substr(i, 1);
    if (charsToEscape.indexOf(testChar) > -1) {
      escaped.push("%" + testChar.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase());
    } else {
      escaped.push(testChar);
    }
  }
  return escaped.join("");
}
```

```html
<label for="input">Input: Uncompressed Link URI</label>
<input type="text" id="input" class="form-control" name="input" value="">
<button onclick="compression(input)" name="button">Compressed </button>
<br><br>
<label for="compression">Output: Compressed Link URI</label>
<input type="text" id="compression" class="form-control" name="compression" value="">
```

You can see above, the html function is where i put my input, and the output, and the javascript function that is supposed to do the compression.

But for the moment he is not doing anything.

Thank you all in advance for any advice you could provide

Comment: Nothing is using the return value of the `compression` function

Comment: Can you supply some example inputs with expected outputs?

Comment: Inside compression(input) function before return statement, use `document.getElementById('compression').value = escaped.join("");` which will feed the output to #compression input box. I guess that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Reason it doesn't do anything is because you're just returning the string and not doing anything with it

Comment: There is no such thing as "a HTML function".

Answer (score 1):

1st: You didn't use the value of the input element, but the element itself. So `input` hase to be replaced with `input.value`
2nd: You returned a value, but didn't do anything with it.. So you could create a new function that will get the value and put it in the second input
3rd: Your `id`s' names are too generic. I changed them to be more specific and telling names which will not interfere with other elements in the same page.

```js
function compression(input) {
  var charsToEscape = "#/%&+,!()*':;<=>?";
  var escaped = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < input.value.length; i++) {
    var testChar = input.value.substr(i, 1);
    if (charsToEscape.indexOf(testChar) > -1) {
      escaped.push("%" + testChar.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase());
    } else {
      escaped.push(testChar);
    }
  }
  return escaped.join("");
}

function insertCompressed(output, value) {
  output.value = value
}
```

```html
<label for="input">Input: Uncompressed Link URI</label>
<input type="text" id="compressionInput" class="form-control" name="input" value="">
<button onclick="insertCompressed(compressionOutput, compression(compressionInput))" name="button">Compressed </button>
<br><br>
<label for="compression">Output: Compressed Link URI</label>
<input type="text" id="compressionOutput" class="form-control" name="compression" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created an `onCompress` function which takes html element as input. The function gets the desired input element, `compression` and assigns the compressed value to it.

```js
function onCompress(input) {
  document.getElementById('compression').value = compression(input.value);
}

function compression(text) {
  var charsToEscape = "#/%&+,!()*':;<=>?";
  var escaped = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    var testChar = text.substr(i, 1);
    if (charsToEscape.indexOf(testChar) > -1) {
      escaped.push("%" + testChar.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase());
    } else {
      escaped.push(testChar);
    }
  }
  return escaped.join("");
}
```

```html
<label for="input">Input: Uncompressed Link URI</label>
<input type="text" id="input" class="form-control" name="input" value="">
<button onclick="onCompress(input)" name="button">Compressed </button>
<br><br>
<label for="compression">Output: Compressed Link URI</label>
<input type="text" id="compression" class="form-control" name="compression" value="">
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Rob sorry, will do